# Python encoding error when turning MySQL query to XML

Tags: python, mysql, xml, encoding, lxml

I generate custom XML files that have to be in a certain format with this scripts. It queries a database and turns the results into one big xml file. I do this to multiple databases that range from inventory parts list to employee records.

```
import csv
import StringIO
import time
import MySQLdb
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder
from datetime import datetime
import string
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import E as buildE
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import shutil
import glob
import os
import logging

def logWrite(message):
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename="C:\\logs\\XMLSyncOut.log",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
        format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',
        datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S: %p'
    )
    logging.debug(message)


def buildTag(tag,parent=None,content=None):
        element = buildE(tag)
        if content is not None:
                element.text = unicode(content)
        if parent is not None:
                parent.append(element)
        return element

def fetchXML(cursor):
        logWrite("constructing XML from cursor")
        fields = [x[0] for x in cursor.description]
        doc = buildTag('DATA')
        for record in cursor.fetchall():
                r = buildTag('ROW',parent=doc)
                for (k,v) in zip(fields,record):
                        buildTag(k,content=v,parent=r)
        return doc

def updateDatabase 1():
        try:
                conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'host',user = 'user',passwd = 'passwd',db = 'database')
                cursor = conn.cursor()

        except:
                sys.exit(1)
                logWrite("Cannot connect to database - quitting!")

        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM database.table")
        logWrite("Dumping fields from database.table into cursor")                
        xmlFile = open("results.xml","w")
        doc = fetchXML(cursor)
        xmlFile.write(etree.tostring(doc,pretty_print=True))
        logWrite("Writing XML results.xml")
        xmlFile.close()
```

For some reason one of the new databases I imported from an excel spreadsheet is having some type of encoding error that that the others aren't having. This is the error

```
element.text = unicode(content)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried explicitly encoding to ascii by changing the buildTag function to look like this:

```
def buildTag(tag,parent=None,content=None):
        element = buildE(tag)
        if content is not None:
            content = str(content).encode('ascii','ignore')
            element.text = content
        if parent is not None:
                parent.append(element)
        return element
```

This still didn't work.

Any ideas on what I can do to stop this? I can't escape them because I can't have "\x92" showing up in records as output.

Comment: You should set your connection's encoding for MySQL. Execute `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` (or whatever encoding is appropriate for you). See [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) for more information on what this does.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem in windows encoding you can try in shell:

```
In: print '\x92'.decode('cp1251')
Out: '
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm focusing on

```
element.text = unicode(content)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 21: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am assuming that `content` is of type `str`, i.e. it contains byte code (only true for Python 2). You have to know which encoding has been used to generate this byte code. Then, in order to create a unicode object from this byte code, you have to explicitly tell Python how to decode it, via e.g.:

```
element.text = content.decode("utf-8")
```